# Typescript Union index based on string

Tags: typescript, union-types

is there any way how to index Union type based on string key something like this:

```
type C = A | B
type D = C['A'] // D = A
```

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't index a union like that. You can extract from a union all types that have a specific base type.

For example for a discriminated union we could write the following:

```
type C = { type: 'a', aProp: string } | { type: 'b', bProp: string }
type D = Extract<C, {type: 'a'}> // { type: 'a'; aProp: string; }
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwlC8UDeVSQFxQOQEMsBoocAFAJwHsxMBnYUgSwDsBzKAXygB9lVwJMsAIwJRBZSjTpNWbAFBpoAEQRQAogA86OAMbAAPDEJIFAvGwB8UAPRWeJ7HgDcRcVSi0GLZ2yA)

Or for a union of literals we could extract all constituents with a specific base type

```
type C = 0 | 1 | "yes" | "no"
type D = Extract<C, string> // "yes" | "no"
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwlC8UAMUA+UCMaoCIQQGcdscA7AexwChRIoARBKAUQA9gAnAQwGNgAeGABooBTgEtSAcwB8UAPTzc+IiQo4gA)

Comment: This is great, I can index by this way also in my project, thank you!